# 2.83 Make Normals Consistent?

Tags: normals

Hey Blender Community,

I am working on a Low-Poly tree model in Blender 2.83 and have the following problem:

Because my tree is for a mobile game I want to have as few faces as possible. So I deleted the bottom of the object. To avoid invisible areas I want to make normals consistent.

I remeber that in older versions I just used Shift + N and I had consistent insides. But now, when I try to do that I am only able to recalculate the normals. That doesn't solve my problem. Also I don't want to solidify the model, because that adds too much faces to my model.

I've already tried to search the "Make Normals Consistent" funktion without success:
[image]

I hope you have a good advice for me.

Many thanks in advance
Sebbe

Comment: I don't get it, in the picture, the faces seem to have the normals set right? Or do you need both sides of a face to be an "outside"? I'm not sure that's possible…

Comment: Yes exactly, I want both sides to be "outsides" without making them solid.

Comment: Normals can only "point away" from one side of a face at a time, however, the material should still display fine on the backside. if you really need the normals to be facing in AND out, I would suggest solidifying your geometry.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is a functional difference between inside and outside, once something is finished. The few times this mattered for me, it was during editing (applying modifiers and so on).